# Exception occurs when push element of two dimentional array into a stack

Tags: c, stack

I create a stack as bellow without using any library but i always get the error

'Queue1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Queue1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x008313aa in Queue1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0072ec00.
Unhandled exception at 0x008313aa in Queue1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0072ec00.

Please help me to check it. Here is my code
Thank you so much!

```
typedef struct Stack{
    int *value[3];
    int top;

}stack;

void push(stack *q,int data[4]){
    q->value[q->top++]=data;
}
void main(){
    int array[10][4];
    int i;
    stack q[1];
    q->top=0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        array[i][0]=i;
        array[i][1]=i+1;
        array[i][2]=i+2;
        array[i][3]=i+3;
        push(q,array[i]);
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that the `value` array is not long enough for the operations. The code is storing 10 items in it, but it is length 3.  It should maybe be declared as:

```
int *value[10];
```

Aside from that, there are a couple of things maybe worth noting (they may or may not be intentional):

- The queue `q` declaration is a bit unusual.  It is declared as an array of size 1 but is used as a simple structure.  It could possibly be declared simply as `stack q;` (with the usage changed accordingly (e.g., `q.top = 0;`)
- The `value` array is an array of pointers to ints, which is perfectly fine. But the push operation is assigning pointers to values that are on the stack declared in `main`. In this situation, it is fine and "valid" for the life of the program. But depending on how the application is developed, that can be problematic (if/when those values go out of scope).